# Stuck Loader in FutureBuilder

Tags: android, flutter, dart, asynchronous, mobile

I'm new of Flutter and Dart in general, I'm trying to do a expansive computation during the loading of the page but the loader is stuck when I try to do something like this:

```
body: Center(
child:FutureBuilder(
    future:   _lorem()
    builder:  (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done){
        print("loader");
        return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor:  Theme.of(context).primaryColor)
        );
      }
```

[...]

```
       Future<void> _lorem() async {
//there is not a request to service, there is a more than one filter on map and some lists. I set the for loop for example of a local computation
      return Future(() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++){
          print(i);
        }
      }
      );
    }
```

Comment: Could you tell me why are you using the loop inside Future?

Comment: Could you give us the entirety of your Future Builder widget?

Comment: @AmonChowdhury the view is a summary with some charts and I thought to insert the computation in a Future in order to show a loader during it, but if there is a different way to have that result I will integrate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with a Future and compute.

In the detail:

```
Future<List<CustomObject>> _retrieveCustomObjects() async {
  SourceData data = SourceData(CustomSourceData());
  return compute(getFilteredClients, data);
}

List<CustomObject> computeCustomObject(SourceData data) {
  List<CustomObject> list = [];
  // expensive logic on data, not only network call
  return list;
}

class LoremIpsumClass { 

// use where you need `List<CustomObject> value = await _retrieveFilteredClient();`
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate how you solved it?
which function you used in the field `future` in the `futureBuilder`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier way to implement this is using a field in your widget of type `Completer`, eg `Completer calc`. You can start your expensive computation in your widget initialization (never in your build function), and when the computation is done you `complete` that `Completer` by calling `calc.complete()`.

In your widget's `FutureBuilder` you should then listen to calc's future by including `future: calc.future` instead of your `future: _lorem()`.

See [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) for an example of this UI paradigm.

Comment: unfortunately also the integration of a Completer with logic on different arrays it blocks the main graphic thread